# Make GridView footer visible when there is no data bound

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, visibility, footer

how to show footer when there is no data in gridview for inserting data from footer.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to bind an array with a length of one. You can put anything in it you like to identify that this is a dummy row. On your GridViews RowDataBound method check to see if the data item is the dummy row (make sure the RowType is a DataRow first before trying to check the data). If it is the dummy row set the rows visibility to false. The footer and header should now be showing without any data.

Make sure you set the ShowFooter property to true on your GridView.

eg.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostback)
    {
         myGrid.DataSource = new object[] {null};
         myGrid.DataBind();
    }
}    

protected void myGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem == null)
        {
             e.Row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working when Autogenerate Columns == false, any other ideas ?

Comment: It should be as I've done it many times before. Have you made sure you have bound something to it on page load?

Comment: This did not work for me because I had DataKeyNames specified in the grid definition.  Removed the DataKeyNames and the grid displayed normally when only the footer showing when no data.

Comment: Also, you can't use this solution when you are using the asp:BoundField control.  You have to template everything.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something easy that i've crafted:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures that the grid view will contain a footer even if no data exists.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Where t is equal to the type of data in the gridview.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="gridView">The grid view who's footer must persist.</param>
    public static void EnsureGridViewFooter<T>(GridView gridView) where T: new()
    {
        if (gridView == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("gridView");

        if (gridView.DataSource != null && gridView.DataSource is IEnumerable<T> && (gridView.DataSource as IEnumerable<T>).Count() > 0)
            return;

        // If nothing has been assigned to the grid or it generated no rows we are going to add an empty one.
        var emptySource = new List<T>();
        var blankItem = new T();
        emptySource.Add(blankItem);
        gridView.DataSource = emptySource;

        // On databinding make sure the empty row is set to invisible so it hides it from display.
        gridView.RowDataBound += delegate(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.DataItem == (object)blankItem)
                e.Row.Visible = false;
        };
    }
```

To Invoke it you may use the following:

```
        MyGridView.DataSource = data;
        EnsureGridViewFooter<MyDataType>(MyGridView);
        MyGridView.DataBind();
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the simple way](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-GridView-with-Empty-Message-and-Header-and-Footer-when-no-data-in-ASP.Net.aspx) to show footer when there is empty data in GridView .