# GridView "kills" page when populated - PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

In a page, I have some GridViews. One of them is terribly bugging me. While all GridViews work as expected, this specific one "kills" all of the page's behaviour once populated with anything but an empty list.

For example:

```
MyGridView.DataSource = new object[] { }; // works
MyGridView.DataSource = new List<MyObject> { }; // works
MyGridView.DataSource = new List<MyObject> { new MyObject() }; // bugs up
```

Whenever the list is "populated", anything that *should* PostBack prints this to the browser's  console:

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: (...)
```

I've tried setting it to a `List<object>` and, as expected, it fails (because it lacks the required fields for data binding). I don't know how to solve this, now.

**Update**: If it helps, the supposed `MyObject` has a structure that *looks like* this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int GridId { get; set; } // the line Id in the GridView
public string Description { get; set; }
public DateTime ActionDate { get; set; }

public OtherObjectId { get; set; }
public OtherObject { get; set; }
```

I am forced to follow an old pattern my boss follows, in which our *models* are separated into Value Object and Business Object classes. See my note below for my opinion on this. The point is, in the GridView, I need a reference to `OtherObject.YetOtherObject.Name`. Is this a problem?

**One more update**: The complete error message includes the string "Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object". Registering the button that "populates" the GridView for a Synchronous PostBack did not work.

*(Side note: IMHO he does it very poorly and loses many good points of C# and .NET, one of them is the default constructor -- he forces me to make it protected and substitutes it by a `CreateVO()` public method. But we all know how hard it is to change a boss' mind. Well, this MAY BE one of the reasons I'm having difficulties).*

Comment: If you need create a empty list, try new List<MyObject>(); the last line creates a list with one element ... probably all props for these element with null values...

Comment: Did you tried using Html.Encode() and Html.Decode() before saving or retrieving data?

Comment: @Mate I know the last one creates a list with one element, the intention is to have a Dummy element so the GridView shows up instead of being invisible

Comment: @AzharKhorasany I don't believe I have any data that should be encoded, all data shown up are Names and Dates. Or must the data I never use be encoded too? (But I still think they have nothing unsafe)

Comment: Try setting DataSource = null, and set EmptyDataText with some custom message. http://forums.asp.net/t/1379260.aspx

Comment: @Mate Done that already. It shows the message correctly. But does not show the footer, which I need for creating new elements. The workaround I found was to populate the GridView with a Dummy element -- but if there is a better one, I'm willing to do it (as long as my limitations - a.k.a boss - lets me)

Comment: maybe, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793045/make-gridview-footer-visible-when-there-is-no-data-bound

Comment: And check emptydatatemplate, I think is a better solution http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `EmptyDataTemplate` seems like a good solution, but it loses the GridView's appearance, doesn't it? Is there any workaround for this or I must try and reproduce the appearance? (Unfortunately, my boss *dislikes* CSS. So I can rarely use it and reproducing appearance can, many times, be really time consuming.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it, with help of @VigneshKumar and googling a little more.

The thing is the UpdatePanel and the GridView were hiding the error messages Asp.Net was trying to give me. Under the hoods, there was a little NullReferenceException happening due to some code that was skipped in the Page_Load method. Seems like the asynchronous postback was ignoring the Page_Load (if I'm wrong, someone please correct me please).

After some googling, I found the recommendation of disabling the `ToolkitScriptManager`'s `EnablePartialRendering`. That caused the page to show me a full-blown error message, so I could see the NullReferenceException and what caused it.

Thanks for the help, and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug you may have caused it or maybe you did not check below for how to fix it.  If you still need help post again so I can provide more info.

http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I don't do any of this page's don'ts. But I'll try changing the async postback to a sync postback and report ASAP.