# show header and footer in gridview asp.net when data source return no data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

**Goal**

show header and footer when  Sqldatasource of GridView1 returns no data

**Problem**

now this is what i did so far i have a GridView in my asp.net application which shows meetings of a persons stored in database 
in footer of GridView i added functionality of adding new meeting for person

but problem arise when a person don't have meetings stored in database data source bounded to gridview return no data and there goes my functionality of adding new meeting because GridView does not display until they have a row

any solution i can show header but how to show footer when GridView have no data
i dont want to use EmptyDataTemplate because i have to reimplement add new meeting functionality (if i am right)

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793045/make-gridview-footer-visible-when-there-is-no-data-bound

Answer (score 1):

Here while binding datatable to gridview datasource , you can check number of rows and depend on row count you can set datasource to your gridview

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            bindGV();
        }
    }


   public void bindGV() {

        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("YourSQlQuery ", cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        DataTable myDt = ds.Tables[0];
        if (myDt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            myDt.Rows.Add(myDt.NewRow());
            GridView1.DataSource = myDt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Rows[0].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```